# Assigning null to variable in finally block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, stringbuilder, finally

The output of the following piece of code is "Test Passed"; can someone explain to me why ?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(new Test().print());
    }

    protected StringBuilder print() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            builder.append("Test ");
            return builder.append("Passed!!!");
        } finally {
        builder = null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use code format.

Answer (score 7):

Basically, what Java does is the following:

```
StringBuilder valueToReturn = builder.append("Passed!!!");
executeFinallyBlock();
return valueToReturn;
```

Whatever you're doing inside the finally block, Java has kept a reference to the value to return, and returns that reference. So it becomes:

```
StringBuilder valueToReturn = builder.append("Passed!!!");
builder = null;
return valueToReturn;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.

`Finally` block will be executed for sure, since you are not returning any value from it, the `try` block returned value will be passed to original caller

```
try {
    builder.append("Test ");
    return builder.append("Passed!!!");
} finally {
    builder = null; 
}
```

Thus, you are getting "Test Passed!!!"

Changing the code to

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
try {
    builder.append("Test ");
    return builder.append("Passed!!!");
} finally {
    return null;
}
```

will certainly print "null" as you expected